# Why I can't install anything in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, upgrade, dpkg

Suddenly,Ubuntu had been getting an error:

```
E: Sub-process dpkg --set-selections returned an error code (2)
E: couldn't clean the currently selected dpkg state
```

I can't fix this issue with `sudo apt --fix-broken install` cause the system get the same issue.Someone can help me please? I need to upgrade and install some softwares!

Here is the complete output:

```
> ****@****:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Corrigindo dependências... Pronto
Os seguintes pacotes foram instalados automaticamente e já não são necessários:
  libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-common-390 libnvidia-compute-390:i386
  libnvidia-decode-390 libnvidia-decode-390:i386 libnvidia-encode-390
  libnvidia-encode-390:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386
  libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-390
  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-39-generic xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390
Utilize 'sudo apt autoremove' para os remover.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-compute-390 libnvidia-compute-390:i386
  libnvidia-decode-390 libnvidia-decode-390:i386 libnvidia-encode-390
  libnvidia-encode-390:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386
  libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-390
  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390
Os pacotes a seguir serão REMOVIDOS:
  nvidia-390 nvidia-driver-390
Os pacotes a seguir serão atualizados:
  libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-compute-390 libnvidia-compute-390:i386
  libnvidia-decode-390 libnvidia-decode-390:i386 libnvidia-encode-390
  libnvidia-encode-390:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386
  libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-390
  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390
14 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 2 a serem removidos e 329 não atualizados.
É preciso baixar 0 B/75,1 MB de arquivos.
Depois desta operação, 1.102 kB de espaço em disco serão liberados.
Você quer continuar? [S/n] S
dpkg: erro: a interpretar o ficheiro '/var/lib/dpkg/status' perto da linha 49469 pacote 'bc':
 valor duplicado para o campo 'Status'
E: Sub-processo dpkg --set-selections retornou um código de erro (2)
E: Couldn't clean the currently selected dpkg states
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple reconfigure of the Package Database might work:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

`sudo apt-get install -f`

If you still have problems provide the contents of "/var/lib/dpkg/status"

Comment: Hi @Sarriman ! Thanks for your tips but these commands didn't works. dpkg gives me an error about /var/lib/dpkg/status duplicated status in bc package.How to fix this?

Comment: Try removing bc package

Comment: It has a lot of "bc" in status.It is really insane to find the issue.Maybe if I replace status might be solve, but I don't know yet what am I doing...

Comment: Can you provide us the info in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`?

Comment: Thank you very much! This works! After erase package bc that contains NVIDIA and then applying the commands that you suggested it works!Now I'm able to install softwares and updates! I just don't know why I can't upvote your answer in stack exchange's app...

Comment: @J-Mello Great! Be sure to approve the answer, so others can know!

Comment: Answer approved!